# How to group box plots in pgf / tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, boxplot

Grouping bar charts is easily done using pgf / tikz, e.g.,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[       
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 4cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    xbar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=6pt,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    xlabel = {Run time speed},
    symbolic y coords={A,B},
    ytick = data,
    scaled x ticks = false,
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
    xmin=0,
    legend cell align=right,
    legend style={
            at={(1,1.05)},
            anchor=south east,
            column sep=1ex
    }
]
    \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(0.62103,A) (0.76326,B)};


    \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(0.84163,A) (0.96132,B)};




    \legend{No vectorization,TreeScore $>2$,TreeScore $>3$,TreeScore $>4$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in a plot like this:

[image]

However, is it possible to do the same thing using box / whisker plots instead bars?

My starting code is this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 12cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    xbar=2*\pgflinewidth,
ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
yticklabels={A,B},
]
\addplot+[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none,fill opacity=0.2},
boxplot prepared={
  median=0.8227,
  upper quartile=0.8873,
  lower quartile=0.4659,
  upper whisker=0.9134,
  lower whisker=0.3202
},
] coordinates {};     

\addplot+[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none,fill opacity=0.2},
boxplot prepared={
median=0.8286, upper quartile=0.94934, lower quartile=0.64128, upper whisker=0.96482,    lower      whisker=0.56093
},
] coordinates {}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

...but I don't know how to group those two plots so that both belong e.g. to group A. working with symbolic y coords doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome at Tex.sx!

Comment: Try playing around with `boxplot prepared={draw position={<axis unit to place box>}, ...}`. This determines where the box is placed in terms of axis units. It is somewhat manual work, but it should do the job. Is that what you need?